# Firebase collection doesnt return a value

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a Angular @Service and @Component which fetch data from Firebase Firestore.

**Problem**
Problem appears when I try to invoke getAll() method. It returns empty array.
Method createDocument() works correctly and creates and instance in Firestore. getDocument(id) method returns an item to HTML, but console.log() inside this detail component also shows an empty value

**Bill.ts**

```
export class Bill {
    public timestamp?: Date;
    public amount?: number;
    public products?: Array<ProductOrder> = [];
    public plates?: Array<PlateOrder> = [];
    public id?: string;
}
```

**Service Bill.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Bill } from '../../models';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DaoBillService {

  fsCollectionName = "bills";
  fsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Bill>;
  fsDocument: AngularFirestoreDocument<Bill>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.fsCollection = this.afs.collection(this.fsCollectionName, ref => ref.orderBy('name', 'asc'))
  }

  createDocument(data) {
    return this.fsCollection.add(data);
  }

  getAll() {
    return this.fsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map( res => res.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Bill;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    )
  }

  getDocument(id) {
    return this.afs.doc(this.fsCollectionName+'/'+id).valueChanges();
  }

}
```

**Service Employee.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Employee } from '../../models';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DaoEmployeeService {

  fsCollectionName = "employees";
  fsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Employee>;
  fsDocument: AngularFirestoreDocument<Employee>;

  public employeeOnShift: Employee;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.fsCollection = this.afs.collection(this.fsCollectionName, ref => ref.orderBy('name', 'asc'))
  }

  createDocument(data) {
    return this.fsCollection.add(data);
  }

  getAll() {
    return this.fsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map( res => res.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Employee;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    )
  }

  getDocument(id) {
    return this.afs.doc(this.fsCollectionName+'/'+id).valueChanges();
  }

  openShift(id, data) {
    return this.fsCollection.doc(id).update({ isShift: true, openShiftId: data })
    // this.fsCollection.doc(id).set({name: data.name, price: data.price, amount:data.amount})
  }

  closeShift(id) {
    return this.fsCollection.doc(id).update({ isShift: false, openShiftId: "" })
    // this.fsCollection.doc(id).set({name: data.name, price: data.price, amount:data.amount})
  }

  updateDocument(id, data) {
    this.fsCollection.doc(id).update({ uid: data })
    // this.fsCollection.doc(id).set({name: data.name, price: data.price, amount:data.amount})
  }

}
```

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router'
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { DaoBillService } from '../../../services/dao/dao-bill.service';
import { DaoEmployeeService } from '../../../services/dao/dao-employee.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bill-list',
  templateUrl: './bill-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bill-list.component.css']
})
export class BillListComponent implements OnInit {

  datasource;
  displayedColumns = ['timestamp', 'amount'];
  items;
  items2;

  constructor(private router: Router, 
              private dao: DaoBillService,
              private daoE: DaoEmployeeService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dao.getAll().subscribe( res => {
      this.items = res
      console.log(res)
      // return nothing
    })
    this.daoE.getAll().subscribe( res => {
      this.items2 = res
      console.log(res)
      // return an array of object
      // services are the same
    })
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    this.datasource.filter = filterValue;
  }

}
```

**Component.html**

```
    <div class="my-toolbar">
  <button mat-stroked-button color="primary" routerLink="/newbill"><mat-icon>add</mat-icon> nueva factura</button>
</div>


    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-title>
            Lista con facturas
          </mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-content>

      <div class="example-container">
        <div class="example-header">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Nombre">
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>

        <mat-table #table  [dataSource]="datasource">

          <ng-container matColumnDef="timestamp">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Fecha </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">  {{element?.timestamp}}   </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="amount">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Valor </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element?.amount}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
          <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
      </div>

    </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
          <table class="table">
          <thead>
          <tr>
          <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
          <th scope="col">Valor</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody> 
            <tr *ngFor="let item of items" >
            <td>{{item?.timestamp.toDate() | date: 'MMMM d, h:mm a'}}</td>
            <td>{{item?.amount}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
    </div>

<br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">PIN</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
              <tr *ngFor="let item of items2" >
              <td>{{item?.name}}</td>
              <td>{{item?.pin}}</td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Just a small note, in `getAll()`, doing `return { id, data }` will return an object with the following nested structure `{ id: 123, data: { someProperty: 'someValue', anotherProperty: 'anotherValue' } }`. If you instead do `return { id, ...data }`, that is using [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) would create an a "flat" object such as `{ id: 123, someProperty: 'someValue', anotherProperty: 'someOtherValue' }`.

Comment: I changed it back - the same result. getDocument(id) returns value of a chosen item, but list is the same. I used another service inside this component, and rewrote a dao service..

Comment: You may need to add additional clarification regarding what you are seeing in terms of your `mat-table`. It's not clear entirely what the issue is.

Comment: I updated a Component to show an issue. Comments inside ngOnInit()

Comment: Just for troubleshooting purposes, if in `getAll()` you used `valueChanges()` instead of `snapshotChanges()` without any `pipe()`, does the list come through?

Comment: the same result.. I couldnt understand, cause DaoServices are complitely the same, but only this one doesnt work. I already rebooted system and recompiled 10 times

Comment: Okay, it seems like `DaoEmployeeService` is working, can you please share the code for that?

Comment: look in the main Q please

Comment: just in case, In BillDetailComponent I have a bill instance fetched by ID, and I can see result in HTML, but console.log is empty.        `ngOnInit() {
    let id = this.router.snapshot.params["id"];
    this.dao.getDocument(id).subscribe(res => this.item = res)
    console.log(this.item)
  }`